# C++. What is wrong with my "hello world" program?

Tags: c++

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with this. When I input "How are you" it doesn't reply "I am Fine."! Please Help!!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x;

    cout << "Write something.." << endl;
    cin >> x;

    if (x == "How are you?") {
        cout << "I am fine." << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Did you try printing x to see what it is?

Comment: Of course it doesn't. You said it has to print something if you input "How are you?". "How are you" is a different string.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but why would you end a question without a question mark when you are expecting a response.

Comment: Formatting hint:  Please convert TABs to spaces before posting.  Otherwise your code ends up garbled looking.  (I just made an edit that fixes that issue.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `std::getline` instead.
As `std::cin>>` gets the first word in the posted code.

```
cout << "Write something.." << endl;
std::getline (std::cin,x);

if (x == "How are you?"){
    cout << "I am fine." << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, maybe you should input **How are you?** instead of **How are you** to make it respond like what you want to check for in the code. Ah, hah :)

Another thing, also more serious thing, is that, you should use `std::getline()` to get input instead of `std::cin>>` as the latter will only get the first word.

Answer (score 1):

Programs are not cognizant. If you hard-code "How are you?" into your program, you best bet that unless your program was in a malfunctioning state, it expects "How are you?". You can ease the restrictions by doing a case-insensitive compare (or converting your string to lowercase) or by allowing omission of the question mark (but then it's not really a question, is it?)

In order to read in the entire string, you need to use `getline`. Otherwise, `cin` will only extract the first word (up until the whitespace).

```
std::getline(std::cin, x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this -

```
$ cat hello.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  string x;

  cout << "Write something.." << endl;
  getline(cin, x);
  if (x == "How are you?") {
    cout << "I am fine." << endl;
  }
}
$ g++ hello.cc
$ ./a.out 
Write something..
How are you?
I am fine.
$
```

Comment: How to use this input in switch statement instead of if???

Comment: @user2998832 Ask another question, and accept an answer to this one.

Comment: @user2998832 You can't, `std::string` cannot be used in switch statements. You need to stick to `if`.

Comment: Thanks a lot and for you kind information I asked the same question!!

Comment: `getline(cin, x);`
What does it means??
Another way of taking input???

Comment: @FaizAhmed Yes. As a [line](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/), not just a word.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading only one word using this syntax.

for debugging, print what you read...

The correct method to read a line is:

`getline(cin, x);`

I pretty sure getline doesn't return the trailing new line, but if it doesn't work check this to.

Comment: `std::getline` extracts the newline, but doesn't include it in the string.

Answer (score 0):

use strcmp to compare strings

strcmp() returns 0;if both strings are same

```
     returns 1;returns 1 if they are different

    int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

Comment: The OP is using `std::string`, so there is no need to use C-style string comparisons here.  C++'s `<string>` provides an appropriate override for `operator==()` that will compare a `std::string` to a `const char *`.